# Can not search arabic in mysql Quran Database with php

Tags: php, html, mysql, unicode

I am newbie in web programming so I do apologize if I say something wrong.
I am writing a simple php script to search in an Arabic mysql DB (Quran database from this website http://qurandatabase.org/Database.aspx - mysql query file format - Arabic(Original)) but I have a very simple problem, which is what I receive by GET method in my php script is not what I entered to search and something add some unwanted Arabic character  to my searched string.
my codes and out puts are as follows:
my html code is:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="ar" xml:lang="ar">
     <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
     <body>
         <form action="p.php" method="get" accept-charset="UTF-8">
             Word Search: <input type="text" name="word"/>
             <input type="submit"/>
         </form>
     </body>
 </html>
```

my php code is:

```
<?php
 header('Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
 $DBServer="localhost";
 $DBUser="root";
 $DBPass="1";
 $DB="Quran";
 $DBTable="Quran";
 //echo "Welcome".$_GET["fname"];
 $Word=$_GET['word'];
 echo $Word;
 echo "<br />";
 echo "<br />";
 $con=mysql_connect($DBServer,$DBUser,$DBPass);
 if(!$con)
 {
     die("DB Connection error: ".mysql_error());
 }
 mysql_select_db($DB,$con);
 echo "<br />\n";

 echo "<br />\n";
 echo "<br />\n";
 echo "<br />\n";
 echo "select * from $DBTable where AyahText like '%".$Word."%'";
 echo "<br />\n";
 $select="select * from $DBTable where AyahText like '%ﻢِﻧَ ﺎﻠْﺠِﻧَّﺓِ ﻭَﺎﻠﻧَّﺎﺳِ%'";
 echo $select;
 echo "<br />\n";
 echo "<br />\n";
 $select="select * from $DBTable where AyahText like '%".urldecode($Word)."%'";
 echo $select;
 echo "<br />";
 $result=mysql_query($select);
 //$result=mysql_query("select * from $DBTable where VerseID=$Word");
 $LastSura=1;
 echo $LastSura;
 echo "<br />";
 while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result))
 {
     echo "salam";
     echo $row['SuraID']."\t".$row['VerseID']."\t".$row['AyahText'];
     echo "<br />";
     if($row['SuraID']!=$LastSura)
     {
         echo "<br />";
         echo "<br />";
     }
     $LastSura=$row['SuraID'];

 }
 mysql_close($con);
 ?>
```

and I enter this string in my html text box:

> مِنَ الْجِنَّةِ وَالنَّاسِ

but I get this string with few difference in output which you have to test it yourself:

> مِنَ الْجِنَّةِ وَالنَّاسِ
>
> select * from Quran where AyahText like '%مِنَ الْجِنَّةِ وَالنَّاسِ%'
>
> select * from Quran where AyahText like '%مِنَ الْجِنَّةِ وَالنَّاسِ%'
>
> select * from Quran where AyahText like '%مِنَ الْجِنَّةِ وَالنَّاسِ%'
>   1

and it cause my search to fail .

I don't know if this copy and paste for questioning keeps my correct output to show you correctly or not but in my browser in  الْجِنَّةِ and النَّاسِ up on ن I have unwanted ِ  or َ in my output.
so much thanks for any help.

Comment: Are saying that when you copy or type the characters into the text input the letters are detached?

Answer (score 3):

The difference between مِنَ الْجِنَّةِ وَالنَّاسِ and مِنَ الْجِنَّةِ وَالنَّاسِ is that a non-printable character is in a different place. Depending on the collation you are using this makes the strings equal or different in MySQL, affecting the query results:

```
mysql> select 'مِنَ الْجِنَّةِ وَالنَّاسِ' = 'مِنَ الْجِنَّةِ وَالنَّاسِ' collate utf8_general_ci general;
+---------+
| general |
+---------+
|       0 |
+---------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select 'مِنَ الْجِنَّةِ وَالنَّاسِ' = 'مِنَ الْجِنَّةِ وَالنَّاسِ' collate utf8_unicode_ci unicode;
+---------+
| unicode |
+---------+
|       1 |
+---------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Change the collation defined for the column to get the results that you want, for example:

```
alter MyTable modify MyColumn text collate utf8_general_ci;
```

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to do a urldecode(). PHP has already done that for you when it was populating `$_GET` as part of its startup sequence.

Note that you are vulnerable to SQL injectiona attacks with your code. A proper search sequence would be:

```
$word = $_GET['word'];
$safeword = mysql_real_escape_string($word);  
$sql = "SELECT ... WHERE AyahText LIKE '%$safeword%'";
$result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($rresult)) {
   ...
}
```

Of course, you'll get a ton of comments here from people about not using the mysql library, since it's deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sample code that I tested with your words and it printed the suraNo/ayahNo/ayah that contains the word.

```
<?php
header('Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
$server="localhost";
$user="root";
$pass="root";
$database="quran";
$table="quran";
$word=$_GET['word'];
$connection=mysql_connect($server,$user,$pass);
if(!$connection)
{
 die("DB Connection error: ".mysql_error());
}
mysql_select_db($database,$connection);
mysql_query("SET NAMES utf8"); //IMPORTANT
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="ar" xml:lang="ar">
     <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
     <body>
         <form method="get" accept-charset="UTF-8">
             Word Search: <input type="text" name="word"/>
             <input type="submit"/>
         </form>
         <div>
         <?php
            if (!empty($word))
            {
                $i = 0;
                $str = "SELECT * FROM $table WHERE AyahText LIKE '%$word%'";
                $query = mysql_query($str);
                while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query))
                {
                    $i++;
                    echo "<br/>$i: ($row[SuraID], $row[VerseID]): $row[AyahText]";
                }
            }
         ?>
         </div>
     </body>
 </html>
```

You must call this after choosing database. When I removed this line I couldn't get any result.

```
mysql_query("SET NAMES utf8");
```